# Zend 2.2.5 error 'initializer should be callable'

Tags: zend-framework2

I work on share host and I can choose between PHP version: 5.4.23 or 5.3.28.

I would like to use latest Zend 2.2.5 but on PHP version 5.4.23 I get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '$initializer should be callable.' 
in /home/rr197664/public_html/domain.com/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:366 Stack trace:
```

...
...

When I swich to PHP 5.3.28 page open but all redirection ( $this->redirect()->toRoute()) stop work.

I tested it on ZendSkeletonApplication.

Any idea what can be done ?

Thanks

edit (replaced server path with ...):

```
Current PHP version: 5.4.23

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '$initializer should be callable.' in .../Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:366 Stack trace:

0 .../Zend/Mvc/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php(142): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->addInitializer(NULL) 

1 /.../Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(128): Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig->configureServiceManager(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager)) 

2 /.../Zend/Mvc/Application.php(251): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->__construct(Object(Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig)) 

3 /.../public/index.php(19): Zend\Mvc\Application::init( in /.../Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 366
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: added to main post, thanks  you can see similar error there http://www.ittopservice.de/index

Comment: This error is quite obvious; It clearly shows you that `NULL` is being passed to `ServiceManager->addInitializer(NULL)` which means that you have an incorrect 'initializer' in your `module.config`, they should be in the form of `'initializers' => array('serviceName' => 'className')`. My guess is that you have entered just the class name or service name without the other.

Comment: This is fresh instal of ZendSkeletonApplication - I did`n edit single line there. It work on php 5.3.28 but when I swich to 5.4.23 above error appear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the last module you edited. Open `Module.php`

in your function

```
public function getServiceConfig()
```

or in

```
public function  getViewHelperConfig()
```

You have a reference to a factory that cannot be found, or a inline a function that is not properly formed

Comment: I did`n edit nothing, this is fresh instal o ZendSkeletonApplication it work on php 5.3.28 but not on 5.4.23. Could it be some server php settings ?

Comment: it could potentionally be any module you have installed in addition. The ZendSkeleton works flawlessly with 2.2.5, just tested. Maybe just try to re-install, there may have been a corrupt file or so.

Comment: Hi Sam,  I reinstaled ZendSkeleton but error is still there. What is strange is the fact it work on php 5.3.28 but when I swich to 5.4.23 above error appear. Any idea?

Comment: The are some known incompatibilities between the latest versions of php, like short syntax of arrays, callable/closure definitions, etc. Probabably there is something around that we havent seen before

Comment: Carlos / Sam thanks for all your answers  so I will try to work on 5.3.28 but as far as I know Zend recoment 5.3.3

Comment: please if you eventually find the cause of this, come back and share the solution!